# JavaScript: несколько элементов с одинаковыми id

Tags: jquery, javascript

Помогите, кто в теме яваскрипта. У меня есть страничка с каталогом миниатюр,
нужно реализовать  подобное - [вот демка](http://thefinishedbox.com/files/freebies/hoverzoom/index.html)

но там каждая картинка имеет свой идентификатор. 
когда я проставил в каталоге всем одинаковый ид то срабатывает эффект только на первой картинке, а остальные не обрабатываются.

Я прочитал что одинаковые ид не допустимы. Как можно поправить код чтобы обрабатывалось по классу? чтобы все имели один класс например class="zoom"?

Обещаю выучить основы яваскрипт в свободное время. Вы мне поможете?

Вот сам код страницы:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Swish jQuery Zoom Hover Effect Plugin Freebie</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=1">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/hover.zoom.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {

            $('#blue').hoverZoom();
        }); 
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="block">
 <a href="#" class="zoom" id="blue"><img src="images/thumbnail-1.jpg"  /></a>
</div>

<div class="block">
<a href="#" class="zoom" id="blue"><img src="images/thumbnail-2.jpg" /></a>
</div>

<div class="block">
<a href="#" class="zoom" id="blue"><img src="images/thumbnail-3.jpg" /></a>
</div>

</body> </html>
```

==========================================

Спасибо огромное! получилось!!!

осталось освоить - [это](http://static.livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_39965/index-1.html)

Эх все впереди! как освою то подключу. а пока что первый вариант. смогу потом расчитывать на вас?

Comment: одинаковый id нельзя, используйте class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите у всех элементов id (они не нужны) и поменяйте код JS на

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.zoom').hoverZoom();
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: слово-в-слово написал, но у меня не отправилось :)

Comment: @eicto, а у меня пропали e-mail уведомления. Нет такой проблемы?

Comment: да я как-то не особо пользовался, но по-моему тоже пропали, всего два за последние 2 дня. (лучше было-бы как на SO, зачем оно в email вообще нужно)